# How do I create a dd image of multiple filesystems in Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: filesystem, dd, disk-image

I have four filesystems with various sample files on them that I want to combine into a single image. How would I do this using `dd`? Should I be using something else other than `dd`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can either have the *entire* disk be imaged, or one partition, it is impossible to use `dd` to put multiple partitions (selectively) in one file. It would require reworking the partition table of the image. You can, however, selectively copy multiple partitions to separate files. Let's copy `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda3` below:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/HARDDISK/sda1.img
```

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/media/HARDDISK/sda3.img
```

This creates two files in the directory of your choice (see second argument). Be careful not to  get the `if` and `of` confused as you can destroy data if you make a mistake.